# Shortcut for reloading extensions in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any shortcut or an extension to reload extensions in Chrome? This is a really big pain while developing extension for Chrome.

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9059987/646585

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding reloading of Google Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057362/avoiding-reloading-of-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: I found an easy way here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-extension-reload/goeiakeofnlpkioeadcbocfifmgkidpb/related?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to actually open the popup in a page.  To do this use the URL:

chrome-extension://{extension-id}/{page.html}

This allows you to use Chrome Developer tools and when you press refresh the extension is refreshed with the latest code changes.  It also updated the extension popup.