# Avoiding reloading of Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing Google Chrome extension. Each time my JavaScript source changes, I find myself having to click "load unpacked extension" again to have the changes take effect.

Reloading the extension at each iteration is very tedious. Can it be avoided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the asset, lets review:

---

**Asset** ----------------------------------------- **Action needed**

popup.html HTML -------------------------- Refresh browser page

popup.html JS ------------------------------- Refresh browser page

contentscript via manifest ----------------- Reload extension

contentscript via executeScript (code) - `location.reload(true)` on background page

contentscript via executeScript (file) ---- Refresh browser page

background.html HTML ------------------- `location.reload(true)` on background page

background.html JS ------------------------ `location.reload(true)` on background page

---

For more information on how to do the `location.reload(true)` see the [page on debugging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html)

The content script requiring a plugin reload has been brought up recently and acknowledged by the chromium team:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104610

Consider using [programmatic injection](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) (`contentscript via executeScript (file)`) to avoid having to reload the plugin for content script updates.

Comment: My "Asset" is "contentscript via manifest", which means I need to reload the extension. Hum, damn. I'll try programmatic injection.

Comment: Note that for `popup.html / background.html HTML/JS` changes, I found it to be faster to simply hit refresh on the corresponding developer tools page - which does the same thing as `location.reload(true)`.